# c++ template type deduction fail in cast operator

Tags: c++, templates, casting, template-meta-programming, type-deduction

I have simplified my somewhat more difficult problem to this:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2660b33492651e92

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename C>
struct get_type
{
    C operator()() const = delete;
};

template<>
struct get_type<std::string>
{
    std::string operator()() const { return "asd"; }
};

template<>
struct get_type<size_t> {
    size_t operator()() const { return 6; }
};

struct S
{
    S(){}
    template<typename T>
    operator T() { return get_type<T>{}(); }
};

struct A
{
    A() :s{S{}}, n{S{}} {}
    std::string s;
    size_t n;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::cout << "Spock out." << std::endl;
}
```

This generates the following error:

```
'In instantiation of 'S::operator T() [with T = char]':'...
```

Why is T is deduced to char and not std::string?

**Edit:**

@YSC's answer seems to be correct:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46608866/4723722

I edited the post to add a solution:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06d31d981acd2544

```
struct S
{
    S(){}
    template<typename T>
    explicit operator T() { return get_type<T>{}(); }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here:

```
A() : s( S{} ), ...
```

the construction of `A::s` from a `S` instance is ambiguous because for every type `T` for witch `std::is_constructible<std::string, T>`, the template function `S::operator T()` is a possible conversion path from `S` to `T` to `std::string`.

It seams your version of GCC starts by testing with `T` = `char`. clang list multiple candidates: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17e247cca8b79c77:

> ```
> /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:413:7: note: candidate constructor
>       basic_string(const _Alloc& __a) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
>       ^
> /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:421:7: note: candidate constructor
>       basic_string(const basic_string& __str)
>       ^
> /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:493:7: note: candidate constructor
>       basic_string(const _CharT* __s, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc())
>       ^
> /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:515:7: note: candidate constructor
>       basic_string(basic_string&& __str) noexcept
>       ^
> /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:542:7: note: candidate constructor
>       basic_string(initializer_list<_CharT> __l, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc())
> ```

---

As OP found by themself, making the conversion operator of `S` `explicit` solves the ambiguity ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06d31d981acd2544)):

```
struct S
{
    S(){}
    template<typename T>
    explicit operator T() { return get_type<T>{}(); }
};
```

And this works (as user AndyG found) because under [over.match.copy] one can read:

> When initializing a temporary to be bound to the first parameter of a constructor where the parameter is of type “reference to possibly cv-qualified T” and the constructor is called with a single argument in the context of direct-initialization of an object of type “cv2 T”, explicit conversion functions are also considered.

Comment: If you replace `return get_type<T>{}();` with `return {};`, GCC actually compiles the code. I'm guessing GCC makes the list constructor greedy in this context and Clang doesn't.

Comment: @chris looks like a gcc misbehaviour.

Comment: Oh, I also just realized the Coliru link has `: s(...)` and the question has `: s{...}` :( Clang also compiles it with my above change if you use `: s{...}`.

Comment: omg you are right
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06d31d981acd2544
if I make the operator T explicit, it compiles

Comment: Neat. I wondered why an explicit conversion operator was considered at all, but it's right there in the standard under [over.match.copy]: When initializing a temporary to be bound to the first parameter
of a constructor where the parameter is of type “reference to possibly cv-qualified T” and the constructor
is called with a single argument in the context of direct-initialization of an object of type “cv2 T”,
explicit conversion functions are also considered. Edit: or perhaps the similar quote under [over.match.conv] is better.

Comment: @AndyG citation added

Comment: @chris Looks like the coliru link was updated to be consistent with the question, both using `s{...}` now.

Comment: @AndyG [over.match.conv] only discusses initialization of objects of non-class type.

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
A() : s { S{} }, ...
```

You are initializing `s` with a braced-init-list, and `std::string` has a constructor from `std::initializer_list<char>`, so this is considered first. This succeeds, resulting in a call to `S::operator char`, which is ill-formed because it contains a call to a deleted function.

When you add the `explicit` keyword to the conversion function, this makes the constructor from `initializer_list` non-viable, so the compiler must then consider the other constructors. Of those, the copy constructor is the only viable one, for the reason given by @YSC: explicit conversion functions are allowed when considering a copy constructor in the context of direct-initialization.